epubjs and getting mages out
I'm successfully reading an epub with epubjs using
let book = ePub('epub/' + file);

but then I'm trying to loop through the file and pull out the text and images using
book.loaded.spine.then(spine => {
  spine.each((item, ind) => {
    item.load(book.load.bind(book)).then(contents => {
      // console.log(contents.innerText)
      // console.log(contents);

      let body = contents.lastElementChild,
          hasimg = body.querySelector('img'); 
        
      if (hasimg) {
        let img = new Image();
        img.src = hasimg.src;  //--------> returns a 404
        document.body.append(img);
      }
    });
  });
});

The text is easy enough to get but I can't seem to get any images. "hasimg" has the appropriate source for the image but I don't know why it doesn't exist when I try to get it.
How can I take images out of my epub and into my web page? Do I need to actually render each "page" to be able to get an image?

I worked out that I can get the images like so:
book.loaded.spine.then(spine => {
  const zip = book.archive.zip.files;
  const re = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'svg', 'bmp', 'tiff'];

  // get all images
  for (const prop in zip) {
    // get the file extension
    let sfx = zip[prop].name.toLowerCase().split('.').pop();

    if (re.indexOf(sfx) != -1) {
      zip[prop].async('blob').then(blob => {
        // blob is the image source, then for testing  
        // purposes I added it to the page
        let img = new Image();
        img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        document.body.append(img); 
      });
    }
  }
  ...

